# Property 'require' doesn't exist in react native error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs, babeljs

I think this error from metro bundler,
here is the image for the error:

[image: screenshot]

I try every solution on the net from the official react native GitHub issue.

1. also try deleting node modules
2. restart the cache

On the terminal, it didn't show any error but on the device, it threw an error. Any help?

`babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
       presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
      '@babel/preset-typescript','@babel/preset-env'],
       plugins: [
       ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
       ['module:react-native-dotenv',
  {
    moduleName: '@env',
    path: '.env',
  },
],
'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
[
  'module-resolver',
  {
    root: ['./src/'],
    alias: {
      '@assets': './src/assets',
      '@components': './src/components',
      '@constants': './src/constants',
      '@navigation': './src/navigations',
      '@screens': './src/screens',
      '@utils': './src/utils',
      '@styles': './src/styles',
      '@redux': './src/redux',
      '@config': './src/config',
    },
  },
],
],
```

};

`metro.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
        transformer: {
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
       transform: {
      experimentalImportSupport: false,
     inlineRequires: true,
   },
  }),
 }, 
};
```

`jestConfig.ts`

```
import mockAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup';

 jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter');

 jest.mock('react-native-keyboard-controller', () => ({}));
 jest.mock('react-native-bootsplash', () => {
        return {
           hide: jest.fn(),
           show: jest.fn(),
             };
            });

 jest.mock('@notifee/react-native', () => ({}));

  jest.mock('@react-native-async-storage/async-storage', () => mockAsyncStorage);

      jest.mock('axios', () => {
          return {
          create: () => {
            return {
              get: jest.fn(),
               post: jest.fn(),
               put: jest.fn(),
                interceptors: {
                request: {eject: jest.fn(), use: jest.fn()},
                response: {eject: jest.fn(), use: jest.fn()},
                  },
            };
           },
          };
        });

     export {};
```

`package.json`

```
  {
     "name": "name",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "private": true,
     "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
         "test": "jest",
          "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
        },
       "dependencies": {
           "@notifee/react-native": "^7.2.0",
           "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
           "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
          "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
           "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
          "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
          "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
           "@shopify/flash-list": "^1.3.1",
           "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
           "axios": "^1.2.1",
           "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
           "native-base": "^3.4.22",
             "react": "18.1.0",
             "react-native": "0.70.6",
             "react-native-bootsplash": "^4.3.2",
               "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.2",
              "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
              "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.7.1",
               "react-native-keyboard-controller": "^1.4.2",
                "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
               "react-native-pager-view": "^6.1.2",
                 "react-native-pusher-push-notifications": "^2.5.1",
                  "react-native-reanimated": "^2.11.0",
                  "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
                  "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
                  "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
                 "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
                  "react-native-tab-view": "^3.3.4",
                  "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
                  "react-native-webview": "^11.26.0",
                  "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
                  "redux": "^4.2.0",
                   "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
                   "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
                    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
                    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3"
                    },
            "devDependencies": {
                "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
                 "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
                 "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
                 "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
                   "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
                   "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
                    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
                    "@types/jest": "29.0.3",
                     "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
                    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.6",
                     "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
                     "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.12",
                      "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
                     "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
                     "@types/redux-persist": "^4.3.1",
                      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
                       "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
                        "babel-jest": "29.0.3",
                       "babel-plugin-transform-require-context": "^0.1.1",
                       "eslint": "^7.32.0",
                     "jest": "29.0.3",
                     "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
                     "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
                       "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
                      "typescript": "^4.8.3"
                              },
                   "jest": {
                        "preset": "react-native",
                         "moduleFileExtensions": [
                                      "ts",
                                      "tsx",
                                       "js",
                                       "jsx",
                                       "json",
                                        "node"
                                            ],
                        "setupFiles": [
                             "./jestConfig.ts"
                                 ],
                            "transformIgnorePatterns": [
                      "node_modules/node_modules/react-native-responsive-screen/index.js"
```

]
}
}

Comment: share the code of your image components.

Comment: https://codefile.io/f/VtakPq51WHT5I5wwEQsh @AnkitVora

This error not coming before but after i implement jest this error come.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

> import 'react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup';

Should probably be something like:

> import jestSetup from  'react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup';

Check the documentation of the library how that import should work.

Comment: not worked, any other suggestions.

Comment: I would comment out that line and all lines depending on it, try again, if it no longer fails (apart from the functionality you commented out), you'll know that import was the problem. So you then can focus on figuring out how to do it correctly or perhaps leave it out.